# Can the interactive legend multiple field selection's default key be changed from shift to another key?

Tags: altair

Take the example from the docs: https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/interactive_legend.html. One can select multiple fields by using the shift key, but can the default behavior be changed so that one can use a different key, e.g., ctrl?

My issue with the default behavior is that the shift key selects the underlying text (see image):

[image]

Comment: Odd, I can't reproduce the behavior with selecting the text in the gallery example you linked. Which browser are you using? I believe you can change the key by using `event.<key_name>` as on this page, which I think should work for the legend too

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior on that example either, but it happens on the charts I make...

I'm using Chrome.

For anyone interested, I could change the key to ctrl by adding `toggle="event.ctrlKey"` to the `selection_point`. Thank you @joelostblom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to change the key from shift to ctrl by adding `toggle="event.ctrlKey"` to the `selection_point`.